# How to copy from local db to compact db with WebMatrix?

Tags: sql-server, webmatrix

I am using Microsoft WebMatrix and SQL Server 2014 Managment Studio. My question is how to copy data (records in all rows, all columns)
from SQL Database (certain table) made in SQL Server and stored
locally to the compact database created in Webmatrix?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO NewDatabase.NewTable
SELECT * FROM OldDatabase.OldTable
```

Comment: I created example to fit your names and it does not work;  
The table name is not valid. [ Token line number (if known) = 1,Token line offset (if known) = 26,Table name = NewTable ]  
Even with  
INSERT INTO NewTable  
SELECT * FROM OldDatabase.OldTable  
The table name is not valid. [ Token line number (if known) = 1,Token line offset (if known) = 42,Table name = OldTable ]
I dont think WebMatrix can operate on separate databases - the sql query is named (NewDatabase.sdf).SQLQUERY_1
which seems to see only NewDatabase tables